# join 2 RDD in PySpark when treating every element as a tuple

Tags: python, join, apache-spark, pyspark

I am not sure how to describe it precisely, but the example is:

Give two RDDs:

`x = sc.parallelize([("a", 1), ("b", 4)])`

`y = sc.parallelize([("a", 2), ("c", 8)])`

, and I want to get the result:

`[(("a", 1), ("a", 2)), (("a", 1), ("c", 8)), (("b", 4), ("a", 2)), (("b", 4), ("c", 8))]`

The `join` transformations in [PySpark document](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html) seems not work for this example.

So I want to ask what kind of transformations can I use to get the expected result? Thank you!

Comment: This post doesn't directly answer your question, but it may help. Along the lines of Zhenjie Zhao's answer - Cartesian: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062168/cross-combine-two-rdds-using-pyspark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the [spark document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations), I find one way to figure it out is:

`x.cartesian(y)`

Answer (score 0):

Since there are some operations for RDDs that mimic SQL, isn't [SparkContext.union()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.union) what you're looking for?