# cross combine two RDDs using pyspark

Tags: lambda, apache-spark, rdd, pyspark

How can I cross combine (is this the correct way to describe?) the two RDDS?

input:

```
rdd1 = [a, b]
rdd2 = [c, d]
```

output:

```
rdd3 = [(a, c), (a, d), (b, c), (b, d)]
```

I tried `rdd3 = rdd1.flatMap(lambda x: rdd2.map(lambda y: (x, y))`, it complains that `It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation.`. I guess that means you can not nest `action` as in the list comprehension, and one statement can only do one `action`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as you have noticed you can't perform a `transformation` inside another `transformation` (note that `flatMap` & `map` are `transformations` rather than `actions` since they return RDDs). Thankfully, what your trying to accomplish is directly supported by another transformation in the Spark API - namely `cartesian` (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD ).

So you would want to do `rdd1.cartesian(rdd2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cartesian transformation.  [Here's](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.cartesian) an example from the documentation:

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2])
>>> sorted(rdd.cartesian(rdd).collect())
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

in your case, you'll do 
`rdd3 = rdd1.cartesian(rdd2)`